# Git - how to delete submodul and create it again under same name and path, if git history at the new URL is entirely different?

Tags: git, git-submodules

This is my `.gitmodules`:

```
[submodule "app/code/EthanYehuda/CronjobManager"]
        path = app/code/EthanYehuda/CronjobManager
        url = https://company@bitbucket.org/some_user/ethanyehuda_cronjobmanager.git
```

I have do delete and recreate the submodul **app/code/EthanYehuda/CronjobManager**, because I have to change the URL. The git history of my repository is completly different from the history of the new repository. More infos why they are different are found at the bottom of this question.

So I deleted the submodule and created it again.

**Delete:**

```
git submodule deinit app/code/EthanYehuda/CronjobManager
git rm app/code/EthanYehuda/CronjobManager
rm -rf .git/modules/app/code/EthanYehuda/CronjobManager
git commit -m "Deleted submodule app/code/EthanYehuda/CronjobManager"
```

**Re-Add:**

```
git submodule add --force https://github.com/Ethan3600/magento2-CronjobManager.git app/code/EthanYehuda/CronjobManager
git commit -m "Add submodul app/code/EthanYehuda/CronjobManager"
```

Now if I go to *app/code/EthanYehuda/CronjobManager* and execute `git remote -v` I get:

```
origin  https://github.com/Ethan3600/magento2-CronjobManager.git (fetch)
origin  https://github.com/Ethan3600/magento2-CronjobManager.git (push)
```

Looks good so far... But if I switch to a clone (staging) and pull the changes, then I get:

```
Fetching submodule app/code/EthanYehuda/CronjobManager
error: The server refused requests to not specified object 9b677ef0e750acb9292030306bd97a3ee2734c61
```

**Why the git histories are different:**

I received a project as a Zip file. So I created a fresh repo and commited the files and pushed it to my bitbucket.

Then I found out, that it is a public github project. So I wanted to change the URL to the github repository. But since they have completly different git histories (My repo just has an initial commit, while the github repo contains all commits.)

So it won't work by just changing the URL's.

Answer (score -1):

I had to call this after `git pull`.

```
git submodule sync
git submodule update --init --remote --force
```